# To gain function the button for generating values

Tags: python, tkinter

The python code I've pasted below generates the values 0 through 100 and displays them in a textbox-like shell console. In addition to this, I added a button deep of textbox labelled 'PRESS'. I would like the process of generating the values 0 through 100 to begin when I click the 'PRESS' button. I have not been able to set this up successfully. Can you help me please?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk
import sys
from threading import *

class Console(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.parent = parent
       sys.stdout = self
       sys.stderr = self
       self.createWidgets()
       self.consoleThread = ConsoleThread()
       self.after(100,self.consoleThread.start)

    def write(self,string):

       self.Text.insert('end', string)
       self.Text.see('end')

    def createWidgets(self):

       self.Text = tk.Text(self.parent, wrap='word',height=38,width=115, bg='white', fg = "blue",font="Verdana 9 bold")
       self.Text.grid()

       self.b = tk.Button(text="PRESS")
       self.b.grid()

class ConsoleThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
       Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
       def values():
          print 'TEST'
          for i in range(101):
           print i
       x=values()
       print x
if __name__ == '__main__':
      root = tk.Tk()
      bas=root.title('Test')
      root.geometry('1000x700')
      root.config(background="light blue")
      main_window = Console(root)
      main_window.mainloop()
      try:
        if root.winfo_exists():
         root.destroy()
      except:
        pass
```

Comment: btw: you can use `tkinter.after` instead of `thread`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you're looking for, you need to attach the function that you'd like to call to the button you want to use. This is called a **callback**.

Luckily, TKinter makes this pretty easy to do - when constructing a button, instead of writing:

```
my_button = tk.Button(text="Click Me!")
```

You can pass another keyword argument to the constructor, `command`, which is a function that will be called when the button is activated. That would look something like this:

```
def callback_message():
    print("I just got called back!")
my_button = tk.Button(text="Click Me!", command=callback_message)
```

Now, whenever you click on `my_button`, `callback_message` will run!

In your specific case, I'd also move `values()` out of `ConsoleThread.run()`; that way, it won't be called when the `ConsoleThread` is initialized.